# MongoDB Aggregate $group for two accumulated fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have the following documents

```
{ 
   id: ObjectId,
   branch: ObjectId,
   name: "lorem ipsum",
   type: "Delivery",
   total: 10.5
},
{ 
   id: ObjectId,
   branch: ObjectId,
   name: "lorem ipsum 22",
   type: "Carry out",
   total: 7.5
}, 
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to calculate the average **total** for each branch per order **type**
expected result for each branch like this

```
{
   branch: ObjectId,
   name: "lorem ipsum",
   deliveryAVG: 8.7,
   CarryOut: 6.9
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) twice to aggregate by branch and type and then use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to turn each type into new object keys:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                branch: "$branch",
                type: "$type"
            },
            avg: { $avg: "$total" },
            name: { $first: "$name" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.branch",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            averages: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.type",
                    v: "$avg"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $concatArrays: [ "$averages", [ { "k": "_id", "v": "$_id" }, { "k": "name", "v": "$name" } ] ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5wfGILKrHmn)

Comment: I'm getting this error   " $concat only supports strings, not array "

Comment: @MohammadShehab fixed, it was supposed to be `$concatArrays` instead, see the playground

Comment: suppose that I have the name of the branch not just the id  how to preserve it in final result